# Volley ImageLoader gives 403 response for some https url

Tags: android, https, android-volley, http-status-code-403

I am using [Volley Library](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) in my project.

I am using `ImageLoader` to load & display image from `https` url.

for example:

```
ImageLoader mImageLoader;
ImageView mImageView;
// The URL for the image that is being loaded.
private static final String IMAGE_URL =
    "https://developer.android.com/images/training/system-ui.png";
...
mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.regularImageView);

// Get the ImageLoader through your singleton class.
mImageLoader = MySingleton.getInstance(this).getImageLoader();
mImageLoader.get(IMAGE_URL, ImageLoader.getImageListener(mImageView,
         R.drawable.def_image, R.drawable.err_image));
```

It loads some images successfully but not all.

For some images I got below error response:

```
BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for https://developer.android.com/images/training/system-ui.png
```

Any solution to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Post full Logcat error. Try to download other image (simple HTTP protocol).

Comment: It's volley library error. So, it gives me only this one line error in logcat.

Comment: IMO, sometimes, BasicNetwork catched exception but onResponse still called, you can see [the screenshot (last line) at my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32478222/com-android-volley-noconnectionerror-java-net-protocolexception-unexpected-sta/32482509#32482509)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not `Volley` or `ImageLoader` fault.

Actually I am trying to access an image of amazon s3 bucket using the bucket url directly.

Though, image doesn't exist at that url, S3 returns a 403 instead of a 404 when the user doesn't have permission to access it.

[Solved by this answer, check it for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19037664/how-do-i-have-an-s3-bucket-return-404-instead-of-403-for-a-key-that-does-not-e?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: The Url in your question "https://developer.android.com/images/training/system-ui.png" exists

Comment: @BNK that is not actual url, I have given it for example.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code but it seems working fine for me.

**Method to send `ImageRequest` :**

```
 private void sendImageRequest() {
        final String IMAGE_URL =
                "https://developer.android.com/images/training/system-ui.png";
        ImageRequest request = new ImageRequest(IMAGE_URL,
                new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Bitmap bitmap) {
                        Log.e("Image Sucess", bitmap.toString());
//                        mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    }
                }, 0, 0, null,
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("Image Error", error.getMessage());
//                        mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_load_error);
                    }
                });
// Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
        Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext()).add(request);
    }
```

**library in gradle :**

```
  compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
```

**And Internet permission in Manifest.xml**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Try with this code please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Together with my comments above at your question, you can find more in BasicNetwork.java:

```
...
               } catch (IOException e) {
                    int statusCode = 0;
                    NetworkResponse networkResponse = null;
                    if (httpResponse != null) {
                        statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                    } else {
                        throw new NoConnectionError(e);
                    }
                    VolleyLog.e("Unexpected response code %d for %s", statusCode, request.getUrl());
                    if (responseContents != null) {
                        networkResponse = new NetworkResponse(statusCode, responseContents,
                                responseHeaders, false, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - requestStart);
                        if (statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED ||
                                statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_FORBIDDEN) {
                            attemptRetryOnException("auth",
                                    request, new AuthFailureError(networkResponse));
                        } else {
                            // TODO: Only throw ServerError for 5xx status codes.
                            throw new ServerError(networkResponse);
                        }
                    } else {
                        throw new NetworkError(networkResponse);
                    }
                }
```

If the response code is **403 - FORBIDDEN**, `attemptRetryOnException()` will be called and you will get the image.

Hope this helps!